# Site reloads after it has been accessed initially

Tags: 7

I've noticed an issue on Drupal 7 site, when user, of any role including anonymous, access site initially, page loads and then refreshes (reloads). When user continue navigating through site, there are no reloads. It happens regardless what was first link accessed (be it frontend or backend).

This reloading happens again, when some time passes, don't know what time spawn it is or trigger, but lets say "Another day".

Has someone got into similar trouble and knows what causes it?

Comment: you question is quite vague. It sounds like it might be something server side. You would need to pin your issue down to a piece of code or a module, or be able to demonstrate an instance of the problem in order for people to help you.

Comment: When you say it reloads, does the URL change?

Comment: Thanks Andrew, I haven't succeed so far to focus the source of the problem, I hoped that it might be well known issue to someone. Alfred, no, url does not change.